# how to separate Unit/Suite/APT/# from an address in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas, street-address

I have a data base 272,000 addresses But some addresses have unit/suite/STE/APT seeexample below

16 BRIARWOOD COURT UNIT B **MONTVALE**, NJ  07645 
100 CROWN COURT #471 **EDGEWATER**, NJ  07020
23-05 HIGH ST APT A **FAIR LAWN**, NJ  07410
15-01 BROADWAY STE 6 **FAIR LAWN**, NJ  07410
80 BROADWAY, SUITE 1A **CRESSKILL**, N.J.  07626
300 GORGE ROAD APT 11 **CLIFFSIDE PARK**, N.J.  07010

I would like to split the text to the next column when it comes across unit/suite/STE/APT

I want to separate these so I can use Advance filter with unique records and create a master find and replace to clean the list....

Any formulas I can use for this would be helpful....

Comment: One issue is that there's no consistency. Some streets have a suffix (Ct, St, Ave) and others don't. Some have apartments, some have suites, and some have a comma after the street name while most don't. Some suffixes are spelled out like "Court", others are abbreviated.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a list of cities in NJ? You could start from there - and that makes the assumption that any street name does *not* exist also as a city/township name.

Comment: @K.Davis Exactly why I’m trying to clean up this list... I can separate the city from the address, but the next step should be to separate suite/apt/# to another column, then the number and last the suffix

Comment: This is what I will use to separate the number =LEFT(A2,FIND(“ “,A2))

Comment: @pnuts thanks I was in a rush when I posted this should be better

Answer (score 0):

You can batch geocode your file on geocoder.ca

This is the result I got:

- rawlocation    Latitude    Longitude   Score   StandardCivicNumber StandardAddress StandardCity    StandardStateorProvinceAbbrv    PostalZip   Confidence
- 16 BRIARWOOD COURT UNIT B MONTVALE NJ 07645    41.035587   -74.06744   1
- 16 Briarwood Crt   Montvale    NJ  7677    0.7
- 100 CROWN COURT #471 EDGEWATER NJ 07020    40.822893   -73.978375  1   100 Crown Crt   Edgewater   NJ  07020-1137  0.8
- 23-05 HIGH ST APT A FAIR LAWN NJ 07410 40.940276   -74.120329  1   23  High St Fair Lawn   NJ  07410-3574  0.8
- 15-01 BROADWAY STE 6 FAIR LAWN NJ 07410    40.920501   -74.091153  1   1   S Broadway  Fair Lawn   NJ  07410-5529  0.8
- 80 BROADWAY        -   0
- 300 GORGE ROAD APT 11 CLIFFSIDE PARK N.J. 07010    40.814151   -73.990015  1   300 Gorge Rd    Cliffside Park  NJ  07010-2759  0.8

From the cleaned up version you can then street compare to extract additional entities.

Answer (score 0):

Since not all addresses have a secondary number (such as APT C, or STE 312), I would recommend separating every time you come across a ZIP (5 digits) or a ZIP+4 (like 07010-2759). This will help you break that string into discrete addresses.

If you then want to clean up the list by correcting small typos and standardizing abbreviations, etc, I recommend using an address validation and standardization service like Melissa Data, or [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com). SmartyStreets has tools for validating/cleansing [large lists of addresses](https://smartystreets.com/products/list) and even [extracting addresses out of text](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-extract-api). (Full disclosure) I'm a software developer for SmartyStreets.